# Solace zlib error

Tags: solace

I am using the SingleThreadedConsumer example of the https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-jms repository to connect to a Solace broker/destination, but whenever I connect it shows the error:

```
INFO: Connection attempt failed to host '111.111.111.111' ConnectException - com.solacesystems.jcsmp.JCSMPTransportException:  
Error communicating with the router. cause: java.io.IOException: Stream error (zlib).
```

This is the correct host and port (although I've changed the details here) since I am able to connect directly using telnet.  This same error is mentioned [here](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-jms/issues/12#issuecomment-345230839) but was not answered.  No Exceptions are being sent to my ExceptionListener and so far I've been unsuccessful in turning up the logging levels.  Help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled compression on the API, but are connecting to the non-compressed port or vice-versa.

What are the compressed and standard (non-compressed) ports used by your application?
On SolAdmin, go to General -> Basic Router Properties -> Look at the Services table to find out.

What is the "Compression Level" and "Port" on your connection factory?
On SolAdmin, go to JMS Adminstration -> JMS Connection Factories -> Double click on your connection factory to find out.